# where can I see my own vm and network security group in azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Because I have created multiple instances of security group and vm, I forgot what is my network security group and my own VM name. Where can I see my own security group and vm name that is registered at azure?
I can ssh login to the vm instance. Can I see it from there? I need to open a port for connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please copy your vm name when login to the vm instance.

Then nav to [azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#home), on the top center -> search box, input your vm name:

[image]

Then you can see your vm in the search result:

[image]

Comment: okay, seems like I already opened the port. when I do netstat -ntlp, it is listed as listen.
but  when I go to https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/, it is closed